# dash aggrid cell to suggest autocomplete

Tags: python, ag-grid, plotly-dash

I created a simple Dash app that loads a CSV file into an Ag-grid. Then, I added a button that adds an empty row to the aggrid once clicked.

I would like that once I start typing in one of the cells of the empty row it will suggest autocomplete based on the values that exist in that CSV column.

For example, if I had a CSV with 2 columns: ID and Names where I have in the Names column: "hello", "world" and I start typing "wo" I want to appear world and a hint.

Has anyone faced with that issue?

The following code for example kind of works but it offers names in a dropdown. i might have many names and it will be hard to find from a dropdown.

```
import dash
from dash import html, callback, Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
from dash_ag_grid import AgGrid

# Load your CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(r'Data\test.csv')

# Extract unique names for the dropdown
unique_names = df['name'].unique().tolist()

# Define the columns for the Ag-Grid
columns = [
    {'field': 'id'},
    {
        'field': 'names',
        'cellEditor': 'agSelectCellEditor',
        'cellEditorParams': {
            'values': unique_names
        },
        'editable': True
    }
]

# Create a Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# App layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    AgGrid(
        id='table',
        rowData=df.to_dict('records'),
        columnDefs=columns,
        dashGridOptions={'editable': True}
    ),
    html.Button('Add Row', id='add-row-btn', n_clicks=0)
])

# Callback to add a new row


@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'data'),
    Input('add-row-btn', 'n_clicks'),
    State('table', 'data'),
)
def add_row(n_clicks, rows):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        new_row = {'id': len(rows) + 1, 'names': ''}
        rows.append(new_row)
    return rows


# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Thank you